# Problema al validar un login java y sql

Tags: java, sql

Estoy tratando de validar un login en java y SQL, pero al momento de escoger un tipo de usuario que es incorrecto, me manda al formulario en vez de quedarse en el login.

Este es mi código:

```
 if (e.getSource() == vista.btnIngresar) {

        String usuario = vista.txtUsuario.getText();
        String contraseña = vista.txtContraseña.getText();
        String tipo = vista.cbotp.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Login log = new Login(usuario, contraseña, tipo, 0);
        CRUDlogin l = new CRUDlogin();
        l.Loing(log);

        if (vista.cbotp.getSelectedIndex() == 1) {

            Main.fa = new FrmAdministrador();
            Main.fa.setVisible(true);
            
            
        }
        if (vista.cbotp.getSelectedIndex() == 2) {
            Main.ff = new FrmFarmaceuticos();
            Main.ff.setVisible(true);
         
        }
```

Comment: Lo que pasa es que en tu validación no compruebas que el tipo de usuario sea correcto o no, lo que haces es abrir directamente un formulario de acuerdo al tipo de usuario seleccionado